# aws lambda file upload through api gateway in java

Tags: java, lambda

Can you please help me to upload a file through API gateway in AWS lambda

can you please share Sample Code to upload a file in Lambda.

I am facing issue to parse the file content in lambda function

Below is code I am facing issue

```
public void handleRequest(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream, Context context) throws IOException {

    try {

    /*  int c;
        StringBuffer a = new StringBuffer();
        while ((c = inputStream.read()) != -1) {
            a.append(c);
        }



        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
        JSONObject accessTokenJson = getAccessToken(httpClient);
        JSONObject attachmentResponse = sendAttachmentToCc(inputStream, httpClient, accessTokenJson);
        sendResponse(attachmentResponse, outputStream);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.info("error in handle request" + e);
    }
}

private JSONObject sendAttachmentToCc(InputStream inputStream, HttpClient httpClient, JSONObject accessTokenJson)
        throws IOException {
    JSONObject responsejson = null;
    String status = null;
    MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
    builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
//  byte[] bytes = read((ByteArrayInputStream) inputStream);
    byte[] fileContent = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
    LOGGER.info("bytesread" + fileContent.length);
    ByteArrayBody bs = new ByteArrayBody(fileContent, "Jellyfish.jpg");
    builder.addPart("upload", bs);
    HttpEntity entity = builder.build();
    HttpPost request = new HttpPost(System.getenv("attachment_save_url"));
    request.setEntity(entity);
    request.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer" + " " + accessTokenJson.getAsString("access_token"));
    try {
        HttpResponse httpResponce = httpClient.execute(request);
        String responseString = new BasicResponseHandler().handleResponse(httpResponce);
        LOGGER.info("attachment save response::::" + responseString);
        JsonObject convertedObject = (JsonObject) gson.fromJson(responseString, JsonObject.class);
        responsejson = popualteResponse(status, responseString, convertedObject);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOGGER.info("error in save attachment ::::" + e.getMessage());
    }
    return responsejson;
}
```

Comment: Why not upload to S3?

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesnt conform to Lambda handlers.

See [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-programming-model-handler-types.html):

You need to have this as your handler.

> The general syntax for the handler is as follows:
>
> outputType handler-name(inputType input, Context context) {    ... }

For API GW to to handle binary data you need to use this [guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-payload-encodings-configure-with-console.html).